# spring boot native maven plugin can't use the paketobuildpacks/builder:tiny?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I was follow the [sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-native/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_sample_project_setup) try to run a hello world of spring boot native.

when I run the final command, `mvn spring-boot:build-image`,the error blew always occur

```sh
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: No buildpack groups passed detection.
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: Please check that you are running against the correct path.
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to detect: no buildpacks participating
```

I did some investigate. I found spring boot plugin use [paketo](https://paketo.io/docs/buildpacks/language-family-buildpacks/java-native-image/) to build image.

I download the sample and find out that

if I use `pack`, everything work fine. but if I use spring boot plugin, the error always happened.

my jvm is OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM GraalVM CE 21.0.0

Comment: Are you trying to use the tiny versions of the builder/runImage?